# Proving that a linear functional is matrix trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W=\operatorname{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ (square matrices $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{F}$), and $f\in W^*$.

If $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for every $A,B\in W$ and $f(I)=n$ prove that $f(A)=\operatorname{tr}A$ for every $A\in W$.

I can understand why it's true, the only part in $AB$ that is the same in $BA$ is the diagonal, and together with $f(I)=n$ it is pretty obvious. But how can I prove it?
I tried writing the base for $W$ and then writing $I$ as a linear combination of that base, but I got stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: what is $W^*?{}$

Comment: @mookid: $W^*$ refers to the dual space of $W$, that is the space of all linear foms $f: W \to \mathbb{F}$

Comment: @mookid $W^\ast$ is the [dual space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $W$.